A very interesting function equation $f(a,b)=f(a,c)+f(c,b)$ implies $f(a,b)=g(a)-g(b)$.
Function equation: $f(a,b)=f(a,c)+f(c,b)$ for all positive reals $a>c>b\geq 0$.
My solution:
$f(a,c)=f(a,b)-f(c,b)$,
Let $b=0$,
$f(a,c)=f(a,0)-f(c,0)$.
Define $g(a)=f(a,0)$. We get the answer.
It seems too simple; we don't even need the function be continuous or other conditions. Am I correct?

Looks fine to me. The condition is just very strong.

We don't really need $a > c > b \ge 0$ at all. It can be shown that the functions $f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(a,b)=f(a,c)+f(c,b)$ are in bijection with the functions $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $g(0)=0$. Namely, to define $g$ from $f$, let $g(a)=f(a,0)$. Conversely, to define $f$ from $g$, let $f(a,b)=g(a)-g(b)$.

It looks fine to me as well: you correctly proved that a function $f(x,y)$, defined for $x>y\ge0$, satisfies
$f(a,b)=f(a,c)+f(c,b)$ iff it is of the form $f(x,y)=g(x)-g(y)$ for some function $g(x)$ defined for $x\ge0$.

Nice thinking though the Current Solution is wrong for the Current Question : [[1]] We are given Positive reals , then we can not use $b=0$ [[2]] When we change Question to allow $b=0$ , then too , Solution will be incomplete , because we have shown the result for Non-Zero $a$ & $c$ [[3]] We will then have to show that $f(0,0)=0$ which is missing & might be unknown/undefined.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772451/fs-u-fu-t-fs-t-implies-fs-t-gt-gs?noredirect=1
